# Problem with jQuery: Infinite scrolling not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Hey I tried to implant this jQuery plugin in my website: http://www.jarlef.com/post/2010/05/25/Infinite-scrolling-with-jQuery.aspx

The problem is the page keeps on loading more and more content without the user having to scroll down which kinda causes the load slowly.

The jquery code im using:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.infinentScroll = function (settings) {

        // variables
        var isLoading = true;

        // setup default config
        var config = {
            'url': 'gallery.php?page={page}',
            'modifier': '{page}',
            'initialUpdate': 'true',
            'currentPage': '1',
            'setupLoadingPanel': true,
            'loadingPanelID': 'loadingPanel',
            'loadingImage': '',
            'loadingImageAlt': 'Loading more...',
            'loadingMessage': '<b>Loading more...</b>',
            'completeMessage': '<b>No more to show...</b>'
        };

        // merge user provided settings into config object
        if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);


        // check if an update is needed
        var isTimeToUpdate = function () {
            var container = $(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - $(document).height();
            var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            return scroll > container;
        };

        // listen to scroll event
        var scrollHandler = function (event) {

            if (!isTimeToUpdate() || isLoading) {
                return;
            }

            config.currentPage++;

            fetchContent();
        };

        var showLoading = function () {
            if (config.loadingPanelID != null) {
                $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).fadeIn();
            }
        }

        var showComplete = function () {
            if (config.loadingPanelID != null && config.completeMessage != null && config.completeMessage.length > 0) {
                $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).hide().empty().append(config.completeMessage).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            }
        }

        var hideLoading = function () {
            if (config.loadingPanelID != null) {
                $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).fadeOut();
            }
        }
        // update content
        var fetchContent = function () {

            isLoading = true;

            // unbind scroll event
            unregisterScrollEvent();

            // show loading message
            showLoading()

            // format url
            var url = config.url.replace(config.modifier, config.currentPage);

            // do request
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) { receiveContent(data); }
            });
        };

        // add content to element
        var receiveContent = function (data) {

            hideLoading();

            // if no content is received -> stop listing to the scroll event
            data = jQuery.trim(data);
            if (data.length == 0) {
                showComplete();
                return;
            }

            $(element).append(data);

            isLoading = false;

            // rebind scroll event again
            registerScrollEvent();

            // call more to fill the page
            if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
                config.currentPage++;
                fetchContent();
            }
        };

        var registerScrollEvent = function () {
            $(window).bind("scroll", scrollHandler);
        };
        var unregisterScrollEvent = function () {
            $(window).unbind("scroll", scrollHandler);
        };

        var setupLoadingPanel = function () {
            if (config.loadingPanelID == null) {
                return;
            }
            $(element).after('<div id="' + config.loadingPanelID + '"></div>');
            $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).hide().empty().css('text-align', 'center');

            if (config.loadingImage != null && config.loadingImage.length > 0) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = config.loadingImage;
                $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).append('<img src="' + image.src + '" alt="' + config.loadingImageAlt + '" /><br />');
            }

            if (config.loadingMessage != null && config.loadingMessage.length > 0) {
                $("#" + config.loadingPanelID).append(config.loadingMessage);
            }
        };

        // current limitiations -> only allow 1 element
        if (this.length != 1) {
            alert("Only 1 element can be registed");
        }

        var element = this[0];

        if (config.setupLoadingPanel) {
            setupLoadingPanel();
        }

        if (config.initialUpdate) {
            // perform an initial update
            fetchContent();
        }
        else {
            // register scroll events
            registerScrollEvent();
        }

        return this;
    };



})(jQuery);
```

My gallery.php:

```
<?php
include('config/db_con.php');
include('config/config.php');

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `like`";
    $limit = '15';

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "gallery.php";
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if ($page > 1)
        $start = 31 + ($limit * $page);                           //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */                                                             
    $resultst = "SELECT * FROM `like` ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT $start,15";
    $new = mysql_query($resultst) or die(mysql_error());

                        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($new))
                        {    
                                            $like_link1 = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(strip_tags(stripslashes(str_replace('shit', 'sh*t', $rows['like'])))));
                                            $seo_title1 = $like_link1;
                                            $new_like_link = substr($seo_title1,0,500);
                    $new_liketitle = preg_replace("/\n/"," ",$new_like_link);
                    $new_status_like = str_replace('"', '', $new_liketitle);
                    $new_status_like2 = str_replace('&', 'and', $new_status_like);
                    if($rows['imageurl'] == ''){
                        $img_url = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/EU8kFP0MI-ceqGK_YX2E68wq1UdDO7FD26QR0_hwaIT8w4DSp2i5I4YKmi7zzXYKT9PX3flDYqQU6D2UkkdwBdc1VA=s512';
                    }else{ 
                        $img_url = $rows['imageurl'];
                    } ?>
<div class="like" style="padding: 10px 0;" onmouseover="this.className='likehover'" onmouseout="this.className='like'">
    <div style="float:left;padding-left:5px;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:620px;">
        <div style="margin:6px 10px 7px 10px;float:left;width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #ccc;"><img src="<? echo $img_url; ?>" height="50" width="50" /></div>
        <p style="display:inline block;float:left;width:540px;height:auto;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
            <a style="padding:8px 0 5px 0;" href="<? echo $site;?><? echo $rows['id']; ?>/"><? if(strlen($like_link1) >= '500'){ echo $new_like_link.'...'; }else{ echo $like_link1;} ?></a>
            <span style="float:left;margin-top:8px;display:block;width:500px;">
                <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<? echo $site;?><? echo $rows['id']; ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="float:left;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $site;?><? echo $rows['id']; ?>" data-text="<? echo $new_status_like2; ?>" data-count="horizontal" data-via="iTweetSWAQ">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=<?echo $site;?><? echo $rows['id']; ?>/&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
                       <?php } ?>
```

I believe its a problem with the jquery code...
I've tried anything.. Any solutions?
My website - where the problem occurs: http://ilikeyoulike.net/

Thank you so much ! (:

EDIT:
As requested here's my calling code:

```
<div id="output"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!--
        $(document).ready(new function () {
            $("#output").infinentScroll({ 'url': 'gallery.php?page={page}'  });
        });
    //-->
</script>
```

and a proper page structure can be found at ilikeyoulike.net/new-likes .

Comment: shouldn't it be like `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: there are javascript errors on your page

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't directly answer your question, but I'd use this instead: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/